# Using Mustache templates and Slim in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, decorator, mustache, slim-lang

I just read [this article](http://warpspire.com/posts/mustache-style-erb/) and apparently [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) is a part of the future of templating. I like the clean look of the HTML only mixed with a few variables in mustaches.

How could I use Mustache in combination with the [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/) template language in my Rails 3.1 apps? And would it be possible to use it with the [Draper gem](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper) or would I be mixing to many different techniques?

I tried using the mustache_rails3 gem but it seems to just add another layer of complexity to my app whereas using the Draper gem seems like a cleaner solution. I don't have much experience with either of them though so it'd be cool to here from someone with some knowledge in this area.

Answer (score 3):

What I've been doing is using slim for the majority of my view and using mustache to render the data (I'm using the javascript version).

In my slim template:

```
div class='template-container' 
script type='template'
  = render 'my_template.mustache'
```

And in my coffeescript:

```
myTemplate = $("script[type='template'").html()
$(".template-container").append(Mustache.render(template, data))
```

The mustache template is just html/mustache.

I would like to see a solution where you could combine slim and mustache into one templating language but it doesn't seem to exist at the moment. This solution is obviously more tailored for client-side rendering but using partials for your server-side mustache templates could also allow you to use both slim and mustache.